# Why do I fail to submit data to textarea with python requests.post()

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, textarea, pyspider

I want to use the requests.post tool to automatically query domain name attribution on this website[a website](http://icp.chinaz.com/searchs),But the return value is always empty, I guess it is because the post method failed to transfer the data to the textarea

```
url  = 'http://icp.chinaz.com/searchs'
data = {
        'hosts':'qq.com',
        'btn_search':'%E6%9F%A5%E8%AF%A2',        '__RequestVerificationToken=':'CfDJ8KmGV0zny1FLtrcRZkGCczG2owvCRigVmimqp33mw5t861kI7zU2VfQBri65hIwu_4VXbmtqImMmTeZzqxE7NwwvAtwWcZSMnk6UDuzP3Ymzh9YrHPJkj_cy8vSLXvUYXrFO0HnCb0pSweHIL9pkReY',
    }

requests.post(url=url,data=data,headers=headers).content.decode('utf-8')
```

I'd be very grateful if you could point out where I'm going wrong

I have tried to replace headers and so on.

Comment: Your request looks fine, what is the *error*?

Comment: I found that the returned result is the result of hosts=''，'hosts': 'qq.com' doesn't seem to work